# Library System: Borrowing

Tags: java, arrays

I do not know how to do the borrowHolding() in the Library Menu I have to create.
So the purpose of the borrowHolding() is for members to be able to borrow books or videos.

This is a just a sample data of the array:

```
member[0] = new StandardMember("ID", "Name");
member[1] = new PremiumMember("ID", "Name");
holding[0] = new Book("ID", "Title");
holding[1] = new Video("ID", "Title", loanFee);
```

This is the borrowHolding() method in the TestLibrary class: (the array is in the TestLibrary class too)

```
public static void borrowHolding(){
    String option;
    option = input.next();

do{

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tempId = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter your ID: ");
    String searchID = scan.next();

    for(int i = 0; i < member.length; i++){

        if(member[i].getID().equals(searchID)){

                tempId = i;

            }
        }
```

So for the method, I tried to write a code that will search through the array to find the memberID that wants to borrow. It is not completed yet because I believe I am not doing it correctly

There is a Member class that contains

```
public class Member{

    public Holding[] getCurrentHoldings(){
    }

}
```

from the name of the method, it is used to store the holdings of the members that borrowed. So if member 1 borrows a book, that book will be stored inside the array, i think. I was thinking of using an ArrayList for this method, but not sure if it would make sense.

To borrow a book or video, there are certain conditions to be able to borrow, but I do not know how to implement this into the borrowHolding(). One of the condition are in the Holding class.

```
public class Holding{
    public boolean borrowHolding(){
        if(status == true && isOnLoan() == false)
            borrowDate = newDateTime(); //this is to get the time when the book or video is borrowed

            return true;
        }else
            return false;

    }
}
```

And there is another condition in the Member class is that the Member must have enough credit to borrow. A book loan fee will cost $10 and a video will vary from $4 or $6.

I think I wrote a few information that is not needed but I guess its better than less information.

**My problem is what do I do to the borrowHolding() method in the LibraryMenu? how do I make that if a member wants to borrow a holding, the holding will go under the member's array in the member class**

```
public class Member{

    public Holding[] getCurrentHoldings(){
    }

}
```

**with the condition from the holding class if it is met, and while executing the borrowHolding method, the method from the member class will be able to subtract the member credit by the loan fee from the book or video. is it possible?**

```
public class Member{
    private int credit = 30;
    public int calculateRemainingCredit(){

        credit = credit - //(the loan fee from the book or video class)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intentions are to add a holding to the member class then this is possible. I would suggest adding an ArrayList of Holding's rather than a regular array because it seems as if the size is going to be constantly changing.

```
public class Member{
    private ArrayList<Holding> currentholdings; // you may need to import the arraylist
    private int credit;

    public void init(){ // goes in constructor 
        currentholdings = new ArrayList<Holding>();
        credit=0;
    }

    public void addHolding(Holding newholding){ // adds a new holding to the members array
        currentholdings.add(newholding);
        credit-=newholding.getFee(); // will need to add a fee variable to the holding class;
    }
}
```

And as for checking to see whether or not the member has enough "credit", that can be done in the borrowHolding() method right after you identify the index of the array. I would just recommend adding a parameter of the member to the borrowHolding() method so you can easily access the variables from that member.

```
if(member[i].getID().equals(searchID)){
    tempId = i;
    int tempHolding; // index of whatever holding you wanted (could get this from the scanner)

    if (holding[tempHolding].borrowHolding(member[tempId])){ // check status
        member[tempId].addHolding(holding[tempHolding]); // they have passed the req. so you can add the holding
    }

    break;
}
```

Hope this answered your question.